# Why does RegisterHotKey succeed with Ctrl-C?

Tags: windows, winapi

[The docs for RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) say:

> RegisterHotKey fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have
> already been registered by another hot key.

And yet registering Ctrl+C works.

Why? / How can I be notified that the hotkey is already in use (perhaps by some other function)?

**EDIT**

My goal it to have a user alerted to the fact that such a shortcut key is already in use and therefore they should choose a different one.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's not needed. Ctrl+C _does_ work as a hot key. But I don't want a user selecting something like it. So I want my app to tell a user they can't use that (or any similar combination).

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is a system-defined key sequence, but it is not a pre-registered hotkey, from an application perspective.  That is why an application is able to register a hotkey for it.

A hotkey is its own feature. Just because a given key sequence invokes a system action does not mean it is implemented in the system as an application-defined hotkey specifically. For instance, there is no `WM_HOTKEY` message generated for <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> unless it is explicitly registered by an application (`WM_COPY` is generated instead). <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Del</kbd> is also not an application-defined hotkey either, for instance (and you can't register that).

If you want to detect/discard <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> without registering it as a hotkey, use a keyboard hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

Comment: Ctrl+C _does_ work as a hot key. But I don't want a user selecting something like it. So I want my app to tell a user they can't use that (or any similar combination). (Also: +1)

Comment: `Ctrl+C` behaves *LIKE* a hotkey by defualt, in that the system has special logic to recognizes it to perform a copy action. but it is NOT a hotkey specifically. Two different things.

Comment: I understand. What I'm saying is that I don't need a way to detect Ctrl+C, I need a way to detect whether there's an existing system-defined key sequence given a sequence. I.e. the user selects a certain combination - I need the app to tell the user that they shouldn't use it even though it _can_ be used.

Comment: There is no API that can do this.  Any application can use any number of [accelerator tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/accelerator-tables), and even dynamically change them. There's nothing you can do to find out whether any given keyboard input maps to an action in any given program.

Comment: @ispiro [Where should I say thank you on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330562/) The preferred way to indicate a comment/answer is helpful is to up-vote it.

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @remy Is ctrl+c system defined? Isn't it typically handled by whatever has input focus?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the key strokes are sent to the window with focus, and if it doesn't handle them, the default handler will generate an appropriate signal, ie WM_COPY for a GUI, CTRL_C_EVENT for a console, etc